# This dependency was not found: * core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `vue 2.6.10` and inside method I am trying to run following line `var area = document.getElementsByClassName('esri-area-measurement-3d__measurement-item-value')[0].innerHTML.split(" ")[0]` I am getting following error:-

```
This dependency was not found:

* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_m
odules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Map.vue?vue&type=script&l
ang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split
```

However, inspite of running `npm install --save core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split`, I am still getting same error

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For me that same error was resolved by using this:

**WORKING:**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-service": "^3.1.1",
  "eslint": "^5.8.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
}
```

Where as the last 3 entries *(or perhaps some subset?)* in this block seemed to be causing the error:

**FAILING:**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-service": "^3.1.1",
  "eslint": "^5.8.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",

  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.1.1",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
}
```